# what to do when isinf() and isfinite() are not working?

Tags: c++, floating-point, infinity

If I compile my program with `-Ofast` with clang, sometimes I will get an infinite float back, but `isinf()` and `isfinite()` don't work. `U` is a floating-point type, `I` (>=0) and `wbits` (>0) are integers.

```
        auto const tmp(f * std::pow(U(2), -I * wbits));

        std::cout << "??? " << tmp << " " << std::isinf(tmp) << std::endl;
```

and I get:

```
??? inf 0
```

Comparing `tmp` to `INFINITY` does not work, `f > std::numeric_limits<U>::max()` does not work. Doing bit-magic (reimplementing `isinf()`) would work, but I don't want to do this. Finally, why would `std::pow()` produce an infinite float when a negative exponent is provided?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does clang's \`-Ofast\` option do in practical terms especially for any differences from gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685487/what-does-clangs-ofast-option-do-in-practical-terms-especially-for-any-diffe)  _"...Assumes the code generates no NaN values...."_ and  _"...Just like the above but for infinities...."_

Comment: Basic answer is: `-Ofast` sets `-menable-no-infs`, so `std::isinf(anything)` can be optimized to `false`. As for your first question, did you check if `f` isn't infinite to begin with, or if `f` is `std::numeric_limits<U>::max()` and `I` is `0`?

Comment: `I` can be zero, but so what? But `f` is never infinite to begin with and obviously `Inf` is still there, it just can't be detected.

Comment: N.B. You are manually (and expensively) calculating `ldexp(f, -I*wbits)`.

Comment: @chtz thank you, `ldexp()` saved the day. I still think `std::pow()` should work as well.

Comment: probably, `-Ofast` broke something in the `std::pow()` implementation.

Comment: @user1095108 Curious, what is your result of `tmp > DBL_MAX`?

Comment: For any further analysis what happened in your case with `std::pow` you need to provide a [mre] -- including what inputs you are giving.

Comment: I did the analysis myself and the problem was the `-I * wbits` expression, even though `I` is a `signed int`, the expression somehow produced `18446744073709551552`, `wbits` is of unsigned `std::size_t` type. This explains the `Inf` returned by `std::pow()`. `ldexp()` auto-converts the exponent into an `int` which solved the problem, while `std::pow()` does not do so.

Comment: Yes, unless the unsigned type is smaller than the signed type, the signed type gets converted to the unsigned type before the multiplication. Someone would probably have spotted that if you provided a [mre] in the first place (your wording that both `I` and `wbits` were integers kind of implied they were both signed). Also, enabling compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) could have helped.

Comment: @chtz yes, it's humiliating :) I was looking for a nice hack, like `f > std::numeric_limits<U>::max()`, which would work despite `-Ofast`, but apparently there's none.